# org mode: show TODO headings that are scheduled not for future, filtered by a tag

Tags: org-mode, tags

I really like how I can click on a tag next to a heading in an org mode file that has been added to the agenda, and org mode will generate a `org-tags-view`, a list of headings with same tag in a new buffer.

For me, it would be very helpful to be able to see TODO items in `org-tags-view` that are scheduled for today or earlier ie not for future.

Is this possible?

Or maybe there is another way possible, by using eg the Global TODO list and not `org-tags-view`?

I do have my Global TODO list to show only not future items but I am not sure how to do this with `org-tags-view`.

Also I would like to be able to generate `org-tags-view` of not future TODO items without having to manually add the current file to the agenda list using `C-c [`.

I would like the `org-tags-view` to always use only the current org mode file.

Is this possible?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Just to clarify, there are a couple of problems with your description: 1) `org-tags-view`, which is what is called when you click on  a tag, is a tag search in *agenda* files, not just any org mode file, and it will find matches across *all* of the agenda files - it is not a single-file search; 2) it will find tagged headlines regardless of their TODO status.

Comment: @NickD, thanks once again for your help and clarifying things. I have edited my post to reflect the things you have pointed out. I hope this makes the question more clear.

Comment: And thanks for providing an answer, which is that what I would like to do is not possible.

Comment: I am certainly not saying it's not possible: all I was trying to do is clarify the question so that if anybody were to tackle it, they would understand what is to be done.You cannot do what you want to do with `org-tags-view`, but that does not mean it's not possible: you can write another function that does what you want and bind it to some other button. That certainly seems possible.

Comment: @NickD, sorry I misunderstood about it not being possible. I have added a line to my original post asking if maybe there are other ways of doing it. I personally dont have the expertise to code it myself so now that with your help my question is more clear, someone may provide an answer.